# How to configure, map and use Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition

Tags: entity-framework

We have a project configured with Entity Framework v6.1.3 with a database-first approach  and `TargetFramework="net45`". We are using Devexpress OData web API service.

We have been updating entities for years and it is working fine however when it comes to large volume of data our **WPF** application gets slow at first time.

We believe when we execute query for the first time it gets slow and then we close and reopen same form it becomes faster so we might believe using Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition could solve our problem regarding of slowness.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/pre-generated-views

We used this Microsoft link to get help however we didn't get much help on this

We have come so far to generate (Pre-generated mapping views and `DataModel.Views.cs`) files successfully as per describe in the link however the further process we did not get much help and getting no idea how we can properly use it

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) dbContext).ObjectContext;
    var  mappingCollection = (StorageMappingItemCollection)objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
                                                                        .GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSSpace);
```

if anyone could help on related to this topic it would be much help

```
    public class objectMapping 
    {
        MyDB_Entities context { get; set; }

        public objectMapping()
        {
            context = new ERPDB_Entities();
            GenerateViewCache();
        }       

        private void GenerateViewCache()
        {            
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            var mappingCollection = (StorageMappingItemCollection)objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSSpace); 
            var mappingHashValue = mappingCollection.ComputeMappingHashValue();
            var edmSchemaError = new List<EdmSchemaError>();
            var views = mappingCollection.GenerateViews(edmSchemaError);
        }         
    }
```

I created above class and call in Application_Start to Generate ViewCache

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {         
        new objectMapping();
    }
```

does any one knows that i implemented this in right way?

Comment: Make your DbContext smaller!

Comment: After generating the views there's nothing left to do but to use EF the way you did. EF will just use the pregenerated views and hopefully perform slightly better.